# What is Trogdor's [Business Model]? How does he make money?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [business-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-model) tag has no tag wiki and 12 questions, 5 of which are already closed and most of the rest of which deserve to be closed.

Some of the questions are using the tag for general questions about various kinds of business models (which has nothing whatsoever to do with programming), and some of the questions appear to be about domain modeling.

Can we burninate this tag?

Comment: I'd say this tag adds nothing, and should go.  Relevant: [Difference between domain model, conceptual model and business model etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25947537) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947537/difference-between-domain-model-conceptual-model-and-business-model-etc#comment40633439_25952115): *I've not come across the term Business Model in the context of software development...*

Comment: I dont understand how is this tag got on stack-overflow in the first place...

Comment: https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/business/software-business-models-examples-revenue-streams-and-characteristics-for-products-services-and-platforms/ business models affect software development architectures so it's not completely irrelevant? For eg paid vs premium apps will need custom gradle files/deployments in android. if someone asked about that wouldn't they tag it business model?

Comment: The title question is a good one. Perhaps he plunders the burninated villages? Maybe he gets 'protection money' from the villages he doesn't burninate? Maybe he burninates villages for hire? Perhaps some combination of these? To answer the real question: Sounds like it's time to hire Trogdor for this tag.

Comment: @reirab "*Sounds like it's time to hire Trogdor for this tag.*" which would be his business model, I guess.

Comment: Do you think this [tag:business-model] adds any value?

Comment: It's not a good tag, but my bet is that it was created by users in the BI field. It seems to be used to label a particular structure in a number of BI tools.

Comment: Trogdor's been busy burninating Flash from Homestar Runner's website.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I agree this tag is off-topic and should be burninated.

I think we should push for the quick (<50 questions) process as outlined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), and not wait for featuring and a second discussion.

I will wait 24 hours to see if there's disagreement on this, then check if I can find another trusted user to support the burnination and remove the tag if there's no disagreement.

Comment: You could contact me — see my profile.  But if there's only twelve questions, there's not much need for combined effort; one person can untag 12 questions quite quickly, even with appropriate editing.  But I'll help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, only need a second trusted user to support the concept (as a sanity check I imagine, it's in the rules), and now I have it. Unless this answer gathers a substantial amount of downvotes or disagreeing comments before tomorrow, I'll go ahead and do it myself since it's not that much work.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39246021/1394393) is the only question I see in that list that might not be close worthy. It's about a specific task using a specific software development tool. I'm still skeptical of its quality, but it seems to be *basically* on topic and I don't know the tool to say otherwise.

Comment: Agreed. Note that everyone can contribute to cleanup before burnination. You can review the filtered close queue using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=business-intelligence). Most have 2-3 votes already, so if 3 more people review them they might all be gone.

Comment: Looking at the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385638/what-is-trogdors-business-model-how-does-he-make-money#comment700639_385638) from @jpmc26 under the question, there are chances that the tag will be created again. Shouldn't this be black listed as well?

Comment: @AmitJoshi Since this tag has only 12 questions in 10 years, and you can't recreate it with less than 1.5K rep, I don't think that's the case. Let's just wait and see if it becomes a problem again. I also routinely check the tools to nip tags like this in the bud if they get recreated, if I see it popping up multiple times I might pursue a blacklist.

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660554/5779732) question? It has only one tag. OP cannot delete it because answer is up voted. Answer is very close to Link Only; but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @AmitJoshi OP cannot delete, but >20K+ users can cast delete votes (it needs 3). If it's still there tomorrow I'll try to recruit some help, and I've cast a delvote already.

Comment: @ErikA that's done.

Comment: @jpmc26: It's now the last one left. We need a domain expert to decide what to do. I could just clear the tag, but that doesn't really help.

Comment: @Joshua Bhargav removed the tag. I think that was the right call. We can try to find someone to evaluate the quality of it if we want; maybe we could reach out to some chat rooms. But whether we find someone or not, we're still going to remove the tag. Of course it's less than ideal if we can't do a more thorough clean up, but we're no worse off than before by having it there.