# Burninate [wikimedia] or donate $2. Please don't scroll past this. ​

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [wikimedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wikimedia) tag (~150 questions) seems to be in dire need of burninating.

Wikimedia is the organization behind Wikipedia and a couple of other wiki sites. While some questions about [mediawiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki), the wiki engine vendored by them and used for all their wiki sites, are on-topic due to their programmatic nature, I don't think there are any questions about the organization itself that are acceptable for Stack Overflow.

### Criteria

1. *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?*

   It is unambiguous, but its subject is off-topic.
2. *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*

   An organization by itself is not programming-related.
3. *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

   I don't think so.
4. *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

   Yes, since it is a proper noun.

### Alternatives

- Update excerpt: As stated, the subject is off-topic, so no kind of excerpts will do.
- Rename/merge/synonymize: No suitable targets exist, as far as I'm aware. People often use this tag when their questions are about [wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wikipedia), [mediawiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki) or even [wikimedia-commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wikimedia-commons), but none of them seems to be a good fit.

Comment: It _does_ appear that there's a [Wikimedia REST API](//wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/) with [at least one question](//stackoverflow.com/q/62656492/208273) asked about it (the only one I found from a skim through the newest 50 questions in the tag).  Part of me wants to say that a [wikimedia-api] tag would be appropriate for this, but given that the _vast_ majority of this tag's usage appears to be conflating it with [[tag:mediawiki]], with a handful of other questions about specific Wikimedia projects that may not be about the MediaWiki software itself...I'd worry about misuse like we see now.

Comment: Buninate [wikimedia] or donate $2.  Please don't scroll past this.

Comment: I'll admit it, @kjhughes - as a former Wikimedia employee, who ran the fundraiser one year... i lol'd.

Comment: What is the bank account for Tag Burnination so that I can donate my $2? /s

Comment: As a founder of a local Wikimedia association, I approve this.

Comment: @mickmackusa The account code is `7R0GD0R`

Comment: @VLAZ: are you joking? :-)

Comment: @Dominique [yes](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/Trogdor)

Comment: Is clickbait allowed on SO? Someone had a question like "who killed the mother?" which was a program flow-based question where there was some concurrency problem, and title was changed by a mod. Not Complaining btw, I like it

Comment: @VIAGC puns in the titles for burnination requests is a [common occurence on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/257542#257542). The question you're talking about was probably on the main site where joke / pun titles won't be very appreciated.

Comment: Should it be blocklisted so it doesn't come back again?

Comment: "Please don't scroll past this. ​". I know it was meant as a burn pun, but I really hate that this tactic actually worked. I clicked so fast.

Comment: If everyone who read this cast just one close vote **this burnination would be over**

Comment: Related: *[What is Trogdor's \[Business Model\]? How does he make money?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385638/what-is-trogdors-business-model-how-does-he-make-money)*. *[Keep the love of puns \[burninating\] in our hearts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316947/keep-the-love-of-puns-burninating-in-our-hearts/316975#316975)* - *"the word "burninate" originates from a Homestar Runner vintage video game spoof featuring a dragon called Trogdor."*. [Trogdor the Burninator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Bad#Spin-offs).

Comment: @Machavity ... you have to help me understand why though. Tags don't disappear from closed questions. Unless delete votes are also seriously abused.

Comment: @Gimby It's a reference to wikipedia's fundraiser banners, which typically include the phrase "If everyone reading this donated $5, we would only have to fundraise for one day a year" or something similar

Comment: In fairness, it's a long way from the year I ran it.  We just said "Please read.  An important message from Wikipedia founder Jimmy Wales."    

Of course, that's the year we also had the pics with Jimmy staring into your soul....

Comment: More info on the meme at https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/events/2010-wikipedia-fundraising-campaign.